# Python: Return all items only once but select randomly. an Item shouldn't repeat in output

Tags: python, list

I wish to output all item from list (1 item at a time) but in random order and not repeating in output, the item which already iterated shouldn't show up again.

here is what I got but, in my output, I am getting duplicates every time.

```
import random
fruits = ['apple','banana','dragonfruit','kiwi','loganberry','mandarin','mango','pineapple']
for fruit in fruits:
    fruit = random.choice(fruits)
    #do something
    print(fruit)

output:
banana
apple
mango
kiwi
mango
dragonfruit
banana
banana
```

i have tried, random.choice(), random.shuffle(), random.sample(). but getting duplicates in output always. how can I solve this? besides I have already searched stackoverflow for possible solutions but in those examples only 1 item is outed as final output.

Comment: `random.shuffle()` won't give you duplicates unless your input has duplicates

Comment: alright the way i was using random.shuffle() was incorrect. below example has helped me solve the problem. really appreciate your comment. Thanks Hobbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `shuffle` from random module to make it easier for you -

```
random.shuffle(fruits)
for fruit in fruits:
    
    #do something
    print(fruit)
```

Ths wouldn't give any duplicates but it will give if the list as any duplicates. (See @hobbs comment)

Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) for more methods similar to this.

Result:

```
pineapple # Of course next time different result
banana
apple
dragonfruit
mango
loganberry
kiwi
mandarin
```

Comment: Thank You for showing example! I was using random.shuffle() incorrectly. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way:

```py
import random
fruits = ['apple','banana','dragonfruit','kiwi','loganberry','mandarin','mango','pineapple']
for f in random.sample(fruits, len(fruits)):
    print(f)
```

displays (well, one possibility):

```
banana
kiwi
apple
mandarin
dragonfruit
loganberry
mango
pineapple
```

Note that this doesn't alter the original list in any way.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the used fruit from the options.

```
import random
fruits = ['apple','banana','dragonfruit','kiwi','loganberry','mandarin','mango','pineapple']
fruitsCopy = fruits.copy()
for fruit in fruits:
    fruit = random.choice(fruitsCopy)
    fruitsCopy.remove(fruit)
    print(fruit)
```